# PHP - MySql -> If Bonus value 1 write Text

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
  $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM kategoria");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
      if ($row['bonusz'] == 1) {
        $bonusz = "Igen";
      } else {
        $bonusz = "Nem";
      }
      echo '<tr><td>' . $row['Kategoria_ID'] . '</td><td>' . $row['Ertek'] . ' Ft.</td><td>' . $bonusz . '</td></tr>';
    }
  }
  ?>
```

MySQL Table:

[image: MySQL Table (picture)]

Hi!

Bonusz ( tinyint(1) ) values 0 and 1. I would like echo "nem" for 0 and "igen" for 1.

Comment: `"bonusz" !== "Bonusz"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change "bonusz" to "Bonusz"

```
 <?php
  $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM kategoria");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
       if ($row['Bonusz'] == 1) {
         $bonusz = "Igen";
       } else {
        $bonusz = "Nem";
       }
  echo '<tr><td>' . $row['Kategoria_ID'] . '</td><td>' . $row['Ertek'] . ' Ft.</td><td>' . $bonusz . '</td></tr>';
}
 }
 ?>
```